# How to format date in LINQ without explicity listing every column?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am getting an error with a Date in a JSON string: `/Date(1370963229000)/ is not a valid value for DateTime.`, and I can fix this by doing a `ToString("g")` on the date, but I don't want to have to explicitly put every column in my select statement.

Currently, I am doing:

```
var people = _context.People.ToList();
```

I don't want to have to do `var people = _context.People.Select({x=>x.Id.....});`

Comment: What's wrong with select?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance - There could be 200 columns in one table and I don't want to have to list all 200 just to modify the date.  I have no problem with the Select if I don't have to do that. I have to return all columns, but I need only the date modified.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? When you're trying to use the data from `people` list, or when it's being populated from JSON? Can you give more details on where the data is acquired from?

Comment: @Floremin - The error actually happens when I try to deserialize a JSON string with the Date.

Comment: How are you doing the deserialization?

Comment: with .NET JavaScriptSerializer, but Like I said if I can do a ToString on the date, it will work fine.

Comment: But, would you have to do `ToString("g")` on the date before you have `_context.People`? I don't understand the process you're using and where it breakes.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1: Use "Proxy" Properties

Put `[ScriptIgnore]` attributes on your `DateTime` properties and implement proxy properties that get the date value as a string. The properties with `[ScriptIgnore]` will be skipped by `JavaScriptSerializer` and the proxy properties will be emitted. For example:

```
[ScriptIgnore]
public DateTime DateValue { get; set; }

public string DateValueJS
{
    get { return DateValue.ToString("g"); }
}
```

### Method 2: Use CustomConverters with JavaScriptSerializer

Use the CustomConverters support that's built into `JavaScriptSerializer` to register your own class for handling the serialization of particular types. For example:

```
public class DateJsonConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new Type[] { typeof(DateTime) }; }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {            
        return new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "Value", ((DateTime)obj).ToString("g") }
        };
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And you use this custom converter like this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new DateJsonConverter() });
```

Date values will be serialized by this class into: `{"Dt":{"Value":"6/11/2013 5:36 PM"}}`

### Method 3: Use Reflection to transparently format DateTime

You can use reflection to transparently convert `DateTime` values into `string` values when the value is being serialized. For example:

```
private static object FormatDateTime(object x)
{
    if (x == null || x is IEnumerable)
        return x;

    var t = x.GetType();

    if (t == typeof(DateTime))
        return ((DateTime)x).ToString("g");

    if (t.IsPrimitive)
        return x;

    var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties())
    {
        // Skip properties with ScriptIgnoreAttribute
        if (prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ScriptIgnoreAttribute), true).Any())
            continue;

        result[prop.Name] = FormatDateTime(prop.GetValue(x, null));
    }

    return result;
}
```

This method can be used in your `Select` statement to convert the object values into a `Dictionary` that `JavaScriptSerializer` can use to emit the JSON. For example:

```
var value = new[] { new { Dt = DateTime.Now, Childs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 } } };
serializer.Serialize(value.Select(x => FormatDateTime(x)))
```

Will emit `[{"Dt":"6/12/2013 3:27 PM","Childs":[1,2,3]}]`

Comment: @Xaisoft, you need the date value to be the string, rather than a child object?

Comment: @Xaisoft, I have added additional suggestions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I ended up just selecting the fields explictly from the Entity and formatting the date there.  This also allowed me not to return EntityState, EntityKey in the Json string as well, so it is what I had to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I never used `JavaScriptSerializer`, but if you have any influence on how the data is being deserialized, I'd recommend deserializing this data field into a string and then have a property on the `Person` class that will return the value converted into a `DateTime`.